# How to select all best N result with same best value

Tags: sql-server

I have table '`reports`' and colums there '`Id`', '`authorId`' and other more columns. There I have second table '`users`' with `[Id]`, `[Nick]` etc...

I would like to **get nick and number of his reports and I would like to get just best records.**
 For example

- if I will have three users with highest number of reports, I will get
  three.
- If there will 8 users with highest number of records I will get 8
  users.

Probably it will have really easy solution, but I got stuck on this....

Thank in advance.

Comment: Google for TOP N WITH TIES

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `top with ties` syntax:

```
SELECT   TOP 1 WITH TIES nick, COUNT(*)
FROM     users u
JOIN     report r ON u.id = r.authoerId
GROUP BY nick
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this script with help of sub query-

```
SELECT U.ID 
FROM Users  U
INNER JOIN Report R ON U.ID = R.AuthorId 
GROUP BY U.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) =
(
    SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) 
    FROM Users  U
    INNER JOIN Report R ON U.ID = R.AuthorId 
    GROUP BY U.ID
    ORDER BY COUNT(*)  DESC
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Group and count the reports, then associate them with an author. Ask for the TOP 1 WITH TIES ordered by descending reportcount. The WITH TIES will ensure that anyone who is tied for first place will be included

```
SELECT TOP 1 u.Nick, R.ReportCount 
FROM 
  Users  U
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT AuthorID, COUNT(*) as ReportCount
    FROM Report 
    GROUP BY AuthorID
  ) R
  ON U.ID = R.AuthorID
ORDER BY R.ReportCount DESC
```

If John, James and Jake all have 500 reports, then the results will be:

```
John, 500
James, 500
Jake, 500
```

If Jake suddenly does another one so he is the sole leader, the results will be:

```
Jake, 501
```

TOP x WITH TIES takes x records, it then looks at what is being ordered by (reportcount) and carries on taking records that have that same reportcount as the LAST row to be taken

If your result set was:

```
James, 503
Jake, 501
Jim, 500
John, 500
Julie, 500
Jeffrey 499
```

And you asked for TOP 3 WITH TIES, well the TOP 3 are:

```
James, 503
Jake, 501
Jim, 500
```

We are ORDER BY the reportcount, the LAST row from the above 3 has 500 as the reportcount, so the DB will carry on taking other rows that also have 500 as a report count:

```
 James, 503
Jake, 501
Jim, 500
John, 500
Julie, 500
```